# Get stack trace errors for IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

This is a .NET third party app hosted on IIS 10, we are only able to edit the web.config, I have added this line

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

But we only get a Blank Page, in the web server, we also tried navigating to https://localhost/... but no luck.

[image]

The Error Pages feature on IIS is also enabled.

Any idea on how to get all the error details (stack trace)?

Comment: So what are the status codes recorded in IIS log files when such issues happened? A web application itself has many ways to hide its tracing information due to IIS/ASP.NET extensibility, so you cannot run too fast on troubleshooting without even reading IIS log files.

Comment: You can use F12 to see if there are any related error messages in the console.